# Command Menu: Spaces in Labels

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, webos, palm, mojo-sdk

I am working on a Palm-Pre App.

For some Custom Functionality, I am creating a Command Menu in my App which has 3 options at the maximum. The options are labels and doesn't contain any images.

The issue is that when I add spaces in the Labels, the menu got messed-up. The separators become thick and the alignment is also disturbed.

Is there any way to change the font size of the label or manually adjust its width ? The maximum length of the label would be 10 characters.